# How do I get the address of a certain variable in gdb

Tags: variables, constructor, gdb, memory-address

How do I get the address of a certain variable in gdb, with the command line that is.

Edit :

It doesn't work in constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile with debug symbols (-g3) and use:

```
print &p
```

With p being the variable you want to take the address of.